# Power BI: lookup and return for a new column specific values in a String

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a column with labels from the Microsoft Planner, similar with this example:

| Labels |
| --- |
| GAB;TIC;COMP;AQUI |
| TIC;COMP;LET |
| TIC;LET;PD |
| AQUI;PD;GAB |

Suppose that GAB and LET are acronym for departments and I need to create a column that indicates which department own that line. The result must be this:

| Department |
| --- |
| GAB |
| LET |
| LET |
| GAB |

how can I do this at power bi (or query)?

I thought in something using lookupvalue or trying to split the string with the marker ";", but is not working. Some idea?

Thanks

Breno

Answer (score 1):

In powerquery you can try this to look for specific items on each row

```
let  Source = #table({"Labels"}, {{"GAB;TIC;COMP;AQUI"}, {"TIC;COMP;LET"},{"TIC;LET;PD"},{"AQUI;PD;gab"}}),
FindList = Table.Buffer(#table({"Keyword"}, {{"GAB"}, {"LET"}})),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Labels", type text}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each List.Select(FindList[Keyword], (x) => Text.Contains([Labels], x, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Department", each Text.Combine([Custom], ", ")),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Custom"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

remove the

```
, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase
```

part if you want the check to be case-specific so that GAB<>gab